# Java Simple Serial Connector (jSSC): getInputBufferBytesCount returns zero

Tags: java, serial-communication, jssc

When using the [Java Simple Serial Connector (jSSC)](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) library, [`SerialPort.getInputBufferBytesCount()`](http://java-simple-serial-connector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/additional_content/javadoc/0.8/jssc/SerialPort.html#getInputBufferBytesCount()) always returns zero, even when there are bytes in the buffer.

Probably related to this, [`readBytes()`](http://java-simple-serial-connector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/additional_content/javadoc/0.8/jssc/SerialPort.html#readBytes()) never returns any bytes. The [`readBytes(byteCount)`](http://java-simple-serial-connector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/additional_content/javadoc/0.8/jssc/SerialPort.html#readBytes(int)) version works - but, of course, I don't know how many to read because of above issue.

Platform is Windows 8 and I'm using the Virtual Serial Ports software from HHD.

Does any one know what might be causing this or how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug. There are a number of [issues](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/issues/detail?id=83) opened on the Google Code page that seem to point to the same symptoms.

As a workaround, [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30010504/1697249) constructed a loop to continuously call readBytes(1, timeout) where timeout is a reasonably short amount of time. The loop breaks when readBytes() times out.